# python: how to create dynamically a function with given annotations hints and default values

Tags: python-3.x, function, annotations, python-typing

I'm trying to find a way in Python to define a function "at run time" with given annotations hints and default values.
I mean, suppose I have 2 dicts:

```
annotations = {'x': str, 'y': Tuple[int]}
defaults = {'x': "some string", 'y': (1,2,3)}
```

then I want to build a function_factory

```
func_fact(annotations, defaults):
   ... # building the function f here
   return f
```

so that calling `func_fact(annotations, defaults))` will return a function with signature equivalent to

```
def f(x: str = "some string", 'y': Tuple[int] = (1,2,3)):
    ...
```

Comment: Just to clarify: You just want this signature for _your_ benefit only, right? Or because you have additional custom runtime logic that does something with those annotations? I am just making sure that you don't expect any static type checker like `mypy` to cope with this in any way. (Because they won't.)

Comment: Please add more context. If you want to satisfy `mypy`, you probably have to write a plugin. If you want to satisfy other typechecker, you probably cannot. If you want to add runtime information, use `func.__annotations__` (refer to this [guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/annotations.html#annotations-howto)). If you need something else, please explain it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Note: No type checkers will be able to work with dynamically generated annotations.
Libraries that use annotations at runtime though can use these.

Now: I assume you function shouldn't run any code? As in that case you'd need to provide that some way to pass that to `func_fact` as well. Note that this might lead to problems as the names used in the code and the names in the function header must match.

How hard or easy the solution is depends on how sophisticated your `func_fact` should be. If you know the names of the arguments and all arguments must have a default, that's the easiest case:

```
def func_fact(annotations, defaults):
   def f(x: annotations["x"] = defaults["x"], y: annotations["y"] = defaults["y"]): 
      ...
   return f
```

Note that you must not have the `from __future__ import annotations` statement in your module for either solution to work (for the second solution you *could* make it work with that statement by using [compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) and using the right flags)

When you don't know the names of the arguments it starts to become harder, the only option I know of for now is using `exec`. I'll show you a solution that assumes that all annotations have defaults. Note that parameters without defaults *must* be before all parameters with defaults. So the parameters need to be split into two lists. I'll keep this task up to you.

Example - assuming all parameters have defaults:

```
def func_fact(annotations, defaults):
   if "return" in defaults:
      raise ValueError("Cannot have a default for the return value")
   params = []
   has_return = False
   for name in annotations:
       if name == "return":
           has_return = True
           continue
       params.append(f"{name}: __ann['{name}'] = __def['{name}']")
   
   return_value_container = {}
   return_str = " -> __ann['return']" if has_return else ""
   exec(f"def f({','.join(params)}){return_str}: ...", {"__ann": annotations, "__def": defaults}, return_value_container)
   return return_value_container["f"]
```

Error checking that there's no default value without an annotation - or just using default values without annotations is up to you.
You can inspect this function signature now with `inspect.signature(func_fact(annotations, defaults))` this will be: `{x: str = 'some string', y: Tuple[int] = (1,2,3)}`